# Understanding session in sailsJs with Passport

Tags: sails.js, passport.js

I have had many problems, when I want to get information from user model. I read some solutions, but I didnt understand.

This is my code:
* AuthController

```
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports = {

      _config: {
        actions: false,
        shortcuts: false,
        rest: false
    },

    login: function(req, res) {
        passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
            if ((err) || (!user)) {
                return res.send({
                    message: info.message,
                    user: user
                });
            }
            req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                return res.send({
                    message: info.message,
                    user: user
                });
            });

        })(req, res);
    },

    logout: function(req, res) {
        req.logout();
        res.redirect('/');
    },

    signup: function (req, res) {
        var data = req.allParams();
        User.create({email:data.email,password:data.password,name:data.name}).exec(function(error,user){
            if(error) return res.negotiate(err);
            if(!user)return res.negotiate(err);
            return res.ok();
        });
    }   
};

*view
<h1>List of my dates</h1>
<h1><%= email %></h1>
<h1><%= req.user.name %></h1>

*model
attributes: {
   email: {
        type: 'email',
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },

    password: {
        type: 'string',
        minLength: 6,
        required: true
    },
    toJSON: function() {
        var obj = this.toObject();
        delete obj.password;
        return obj;
    }
},
    beforeCreate: function(user, cb) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    cb(err);
                } else {
                    user.password = hash;
                    cb();
                }
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Only works if I use res.render('view', {email: req.user.email}) but, I would like to use the user data in many views. I cant write methods with Current user params, becouse dont work.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, the model instance method (toJson) is dropped in v1 so i would no count on this to work. See at the end here: http://0.12.sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/models

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me what your actual problem is or what the question actually is but I will try to help.

Look here:

```
login: function(req, res) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if ((err) || (!user)) {
      return res.send({
        message: info.message,
        user: user
      });
    }
    ...
  })(req, res);
},
```

There you are adding data (locals) to the ejs and the values are `message` and `user` so in the ejs you must reference it as this, so you will use `user.name` and not `req.user.name`? I'm not sure why you're binding the `(req, res)` either.

It's confusing because your ejs uses the email value but I don't see it there as a local so maybe thats your problem, it must be defined?

Consider the following simple example:

```
// User Controller

// GET request /signin
// The signin form
signin(req, res) {
  // Load the view from app/views/*
  return res.view('signin', {
    title: 'Sign In'
  });
},

// POST request to /signin
// This was posted from the signin form
// Use io.socket.post(...) to do this from the signin form
// Can use window.location.replace('/account') on successful request
authenticate(req, res) {
  // The data posted, email and password attempt
  var data = req.allParams();
  // Does it match?
  User.findOne({
    email: data.email,
    // This is stupid, don't ever use plain text passwords
    password: data.password
  })
  .exec(function(err, user) {
    // Server related error?
    if (err) res.serverError(err.message);
    // No user was found
    if (!user) res.badRequest('Username or password not found');
    // Sign the user in
    req.session.userId = user.id;
    // User was found
    res.ok();
  });
},

// GET request to /account
// Displays the users information
// Can use policies to ensure that only an authenticated user may access their own account information
account(req, res) {
  // If the user is not signed in
  // This is an alternative to using the sails policy isLoggedIn
  if (!req.session.userId) res.redirect('/signin');
  // Get the users details
  User.findOne({
    id: req.session.userId
  })
  .exec(function(err, user) {
    // Server related error?
    if (err) res.serverError(err.message);
    // No user was found
    if (!user) res.redirect('/signin');
    // Load the ejs file that displays the users information
    return res.view('account/index', {
      title: 'Account Information',
      user: user
    });
  });
},

// Account View

<p>Email: {{user.email}}</p>
<p>Password: {{user.password}}</p>
```

Check this out if you want to deal with password encryption: http://node-machine.org/machinepack-passwords

And this if you want to deal with the strength tests (when the user sets the password): https://www.npmjs.com/package/owasp-password-strength-test

This is as passport seems overkill if you're only doing local authentication?

Comment: Thanks for answer me. Yes, this is my problem. I cant get User information from the view. I try with req.user.name and with user.name, but nothing happens. The answer is "undefined".
I will see this articles. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @FranciscoPossetto Take a look at my example to ensure that you understand how the locals(data) are working in ejs, then, edit the question and add the controller action/method which is loading the view code? I can't see it, am I blind?